# Rails 4 : Error when trying to sort by using arel_table.maximum.desc

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sorting

I got an `Order` and a `Product` model with a Many-to-Many relationship. So an order `has_many` products, each of them has different prices.

Now I want to sort the orders with the maximum price of the product that an order has.

Here is my code:

```
@orders = Order.group(arel_table[:id]).
                order(Product.arel_table[:price].maximum)
```

It works perfectly with the default ASC order, but when I sort it as DESC order like this:

```
@orders = Order.group(arel_table[:id]).
                order(Product.arel_table[:price].maximum.desc)
```

I got an error like this :

```
undefined method `desc' for #<Arel::Nodes::Max:0x007fb2ab9104a0>
```

How can I sort the orders as DESC?

Comment: hey, you should check the answers and [accept the one that worked for you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)...

Comment: So sorry, this my first try at stack overflow and forgot to pick the answer.Great help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work:

```ruby
@orders = Order
            .group(arel_table[:id]) # Maybe Order.arel_table[:id] 
            .order(Arel::Nodes::Descending.new(Product.arel_table[:price].maximum))
```

Please see also:

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/Arel/OrderPredications#desc-instance_method

Answer (score 1):

First of all, plain old `ActiveRecord` will do for this task.

My attempt is to first select the `max_price` of the product via a join.

```
Order.select('users.id, MAX(products.price) AS max_price').group('orders.id')

+----+-----------+
| id | max_price |
+----+-----------+
| 1  |    850    |
| 2  |    240    |
| 3  |    200    |
| 4  |    100    |
| 5  |    300    |
+----+-----------+
```

After that, it's an easy task to order the `max_price` as requested.

```
.order('max_price DESC')
.order('max_price ASC')

+----+-----------+
| id | max_price |
+----+-----------+
| 4  |    100    |
| 3  |    200    |
| 2  |    240    |
| 5  |    300    |
| 1  |    850    |
+----+-----------+
```

I'm sure this will get you going ;). Of course, feel free to select more than just the `id`.

Comment: Plain sql works fine, but I just try to use the are_table to write more rails like code

Comment: using arel is *definitely* not the rails way to go - there's a reason why `ActiveRecord` was built

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@orders = Order.group(arel_table[:id]).
            order(Product.arel_table[:price].maximum: :desc)
```